# I have to read numbers from a text file and store each one in a different object, Help Please. java

Tags: java, file, object, text

EDIT: Found out what I was doing wrong. The double array in the StockDataBase class was declared static. :( sorry for the trouble everyone.

I have to read from a text file. It basically contains numbers in two columns. I have to store the left column in an object and the right in another. I've tried to do this, but it's storing the right column in both. Please Help, could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

values.txt:

100.0     110
100.0     100.0

100.0     105.0
100.0     120.0
100       101.0
100.0     100.0

100.0      90.0
100.0      70.0
100.0      83.0
100        80.0
100.0      99
100.0      50.0

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class StockAnalysis {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StockDataBase startingValue = new StockDataBase();
        StockDataBase endingValue = new StockDataBase();

        try {
            Scanner input= new Scanner(new File("values.txt"));

           int i = 0;

           while(input.hasNext()){

               startingValue.setStockValue(i,input.nextDouble());
               endingValue.setStockValue(i, input.nextDouble());
               i++;

           }
           input.close();

           /*
           Scanner input2 = new Scanner(new File("values.txt"));
           i=0;
           while(input2.hasNext()){
               double temp = input2.nextDouble();
               endingValue.setStockValue(i, input2.nextDouble());
               i++;

           }*/

            for(int z = 0; z < 12; z++){
                System.out.println(endingValue.getStockValue(z));
            }


       } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open or read from file.");
       }
    }
}
```

---

This just prints out the same values for both of them. I tried to create another scanner and do each one separately where one would skip the first or the second line by storing it in a temporary double variable. That didn't work either. Thanks for helping

Comment: Are you separating values in the txt with an empty space?

Comment: those columns, how are they separated? Space? Tabulator?

Comment: I don't see where you're printing out the values from `startingValue`.

Comment: Liberal use of print will debug this quickly.

Comment: The values are separated by arbitrary number of spaces.
i.e. 
100    10.0
100.0    21.3

Comment: @n.k, can you post input data, please?

Comment: @RafaeldAS  I found out what I was doing wrong. The array that I was trying to put the values in was declared Static in my StockDataBase class. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program doesnt have any problems. I used this with the below input and works fine. Now the only possibility for error is the `StockDataBase` class. Please share that to see how your are adding and retrieveing value. I just used a hashmap as shown below.

Values.txt

```
100.0 10.0
200.0 21.3
101.0 10.0
220.0 24.3
130.0 15.0
204.0 21.3
100.0 10.0
260.0 27.3
100.0 10.0
205.0 81.3
100.0 16.5
260.0 21.3
```

StockDataBase.java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class StockDataBase {

    Map<Integer, Double> values = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();

    public void setStockValue(int i, double nextDouble) {
        values.put(i, nextDouble);

    }

    public Double getStockValue(int z) {
        return values.get(z);
    }

}
```

Main Class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StockAnalysis {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StockDataBase startingValue = new StockDataBase();
        StockDataBase endingValue = new StockDataBase();

        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("values.txt"));

            int i = 0;

            while (input.hasNext()) {
                startingValue.setStockValue(i, input.nextDouble());
                endingValue.setStockValue(i, input.nextDouble());
                i++;

            }
            input.close();

            for (int z = 0; z < 12; z++) {
                System.out.println("Left : " + startingValue.getStockValue(z) + ", Right : " + endingValue.getStockValue(z));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open or read from file.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, the array was declared static in the StockDataBase class. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it works for you but heres my solution:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StockAnalysis {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("values.txt"));

            int i = 0;

            while (input.hasNext()) {

                System.out.println(i +":" +input.nextDouble());
                i++;
                System.out.println(i +":" +input.nextDouble());
                i++;

            }
            input.close();





        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open or read from file.");
        }
    }
}
```

here's the content of my values.txt

```
1 2
21 23
24 25
31 39
```

And here's the output

```
0:1.0
1:2.0
2:21.0
3:23.0
4:24.0
5:25.0
6:31.0
7:39.0
```

As far as I could see, your code is correct. Maybe you have to fix the "i" position to match the correct position of your object?

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer, but I need to have the values stored in the different objects. Each object has a double array data field and I need to store the first column in one of them and the next in another.